# Need help finding the correct css selector for shadow dom elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver, shadow-dom

I am looking to find the css selector for the download button. It is located in a shadow dom element. I am getting some issues when I try to find it.

This is what I am doing in the js executor

```
return document.querySelector('pdf-viewer')\
.shadowRoot.querySelector('viewer-toolbar')\
.shadowRoot.querySelector('viewer-download-cobtrols')\
.shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-icon-button').click()
```

Was wondering if anyone on here can help